# how does google measure app works on android?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, google-apps, video-processing

I can see that it can measure horizontal and vertical distances with +/-5% accuracy. I have a use case scenario in which I am trying to formulate an algorithm to detect distances between two points in an image or video. Any pointers to how it could be working would be very useful to me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the source is available for the Android measure app, but it is ARCore based and I would expect it uses a combination of triangulation and knowledge it reads from the 'scene', using the Google ARCore term, it is viewing.

Like a human estimating distance to a point, by basic triangulation between two eyes and the point being looked at, a measurement app is able to look at multiple views of the scene and to measure using its sensors how far the device has moved between the different views. Even a small movement allows the same triangulation techniques be used.

The reason for mentioning all this is to highlight that you do not have the same tools or information available to you if you are analysing image or video files without any position or sensor data. Hence, the Google measure app may not be the best template for you to look to for your particular problem.

Comment: So they might be using IMU Sensor data to compute the change in the location of the camera center. I would presume that for such a high accuracy the calculation has be very precise.

Comment: They should be able to leverage averaged calculations over a number of captured frames - it would be interesting to see what would happen if the phone was in a fixed stand pointed at something with few features like a white wall.

Comment: There two factors here, first the app works only on pixel devices for some reason and second when the app is started they indicate that the phone should be moved in a certain way, so keeping it constant didn't work I tested this.

Comment: Yes, ARCore is only supported on certain devices so app are limited to those devices - it should work on Galaxy S9 and some other devices now also, as an aside. The movement is to allow ARCore detect planes - unfortunately, AFAIK, the algorithms and code used are not open to view.